# Aframe. How to make entities appear when click in another entity

Tags: javascript, html, aframe

I have 2 boxes in A-FRAME (0.9.2), i want to make the second box (red) appear when click on the first (green). At the beginning, the red box is not visible but i want it to appear and disappear when click in the green box.

```js
AFRAME.registerComponent('cajaverde', {
      init: function() {
        this.el.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
          let aparecer = document.querySelector("#cajaroja")
          aparecer.setAttribute("visible", !aparecer.getAttribute("visible"))
        })
      }
    })
```

And here are my boxes:

```html
      <a-box caja id="cajaroja" color="#b51628" depth=".1" height="1" width="0.9" position="1 2.6 -2" visible="false"></a-box>
      <a-box caja id="cajaverde" color="#44cf67" depth=".1" height="1" width="0.9" position="-0.5 2.6 -2"></a-box>
```

When i click the green box nothing happens.

I also have the code [here](https://glitch.com/~ultraman-2)

Answer (score 0):

If your component is called `cajaverde` then you need to use its full name.

Instead of

```
<a-box caja ...
```

There should be

```
<a-box cajaverde ...
```

And only on the one which is supposed to be the button.

---

working glitch [here](https://stack-58651003.glitch.me/).